# Fancybox urls without .jpg opens not in box

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have seen a similar question here :
[Fancybox chokes on a URL that contains "&"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241957/fancybox-chokes-on-a-url-that-contains)
And I have tried all offered solutions but none of them work !
I have included correctly all links, ( the jquery link first )
 I checked, and at the beginning of my document, I declared fancybox like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({'type' : 'image'});
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
  });
});
</script>
```

My code is :

```
   echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="square/'.$fic_serie .'">
<img src="square/'.$fic_serie .'" alt=""/></a>';
```

$fic_serie is the var that will get replaced by the image name

Right now, I feel like nothing works; the images are way too big compared to how I said they should be ( in the fancybox.js file ) and when I click on them, they open as a link, not in lightbox.

I have also tried

```
class='fancybox fancybox.image'
```

but without luck....
Thank you !

Comment: what does the php render to? what is an example `$fic_serie`

Comment: Check your jQuery you have syntax errors, opening and closing parens and braces don't match

Comment: It generates links lile this `<div id="contenu_artist"><a class="fancybox" href="square/booth-camp-1m_1_x-1.jpg" rel="group1"><img alt="" src="square/booth-camp-1m_1_x-1.jpg"></img></a><a class="fancybox" href="square/booth-camp-2_x.jpg" rel="group1"> … </a><a class="fancybox" href="square/booth-camp-3_x.jpg" rel="group1"> … </a>`. I tried re-writing the jquery like you suggested cjross, but still not working ( adress of the page : http://ondinevermenot.fr/ok/artist.php?ID=79 )

Comment: I just tried with a png image, to see if it was because of him not recognizing the image format but it doesn't work either !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type        : 'image',
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why and more alternatives to this code can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17554660/1055987