# Fancybox opens new window

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, fancybox

So I am using this rails gem: https://github.com/kyparn/fancybox2-rails

- Using BackboneJS for frontend and instantiating fancybox in the View

Fancybox works perfectly locally but on staging and production, images are opened in a new window. I checked chrome console and made sure that fancybox was present, and it is.

Not entirely sure how to resolve this / go about debugging this.

This is how I have images setup:

```
   <a class="fancybox-image" data-fancybox="image" href="image_url">
   <img src="image_url" data-js="activate-img-modal">
   </a>
```

I am instantiating fancybox setup in the Backbone View where each image is in.

```
  setupFancyBox: function() {
     var options = {
       helpers: {
         overlay: {
           locked: false
         }
        }
      };
      this.$("[data-fancybox='image']").fancybox(options);
  }
```

- This function is called in the View's render method.

Comment: most likely another js error (hoisting, jQuery version conflicts, etc.) is preventing fancybox from working ... but without any code or jsfiddle is just a guess

Comment: Console brings up no JS errors.

Comment: I am not very familiar with BackboneJS, but what mean "this" in last line? Maybe it should by without this keyword, just $("[data-fancybox='image']").fancybox(options);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So locally there were extensions on my images (.jpg/.png) like so:

```
 <a class="fancybox-image" data-fancybox="image" href="path/to/image1.png">
   <img src="path/to/image1.png" data-js="activate-img-modal">
 </a>
```

But on production/live there were no image extensions:

```
 <a class="fancybox-image" data-fancybox="image" href="path/to/image1.">
   <img src="path/to/image1." data-js="activate-img-modal">
 </a>
```

Missing the extension, caused fancybox not to activate for me.

A Fix would be taken from here ([Fancybox urls without .jpg opens not in box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547727/fancybox-urls-without-jpg-opens-not-in-box)):

```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: 'image'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check javascript console, if appears some javascript error it can prevent from further javascript code execution.
Next step try initialize fancybox in console, simply run this code (of course use your own selector)

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox();
```

Comment: I tried this and it is able to select the 'a' tags that wrap the images for fancybox. And fancybox is present.

Comment: How and where you put your fancybox initialization code? You should put it on document ready event.

Comment: I just updated the question